# Null Checks in C++

Tags: c++, null

I'm trying to get NULL or nullptr to work in C++.

Say I'm doing an inorder traversal of a binary tree, like so:

```
template <class DataType>
void printInorder(someNode<DataType>* node)
{
     if (node == NULL)
          return;

     /* first recur on left child */
     printInorder(node->left);

     /* then print the data of node */
     printf("%d ", node->data);  

     /* now recur on right child */
     printInorder(node->right);
}
```

I have tried setting if(node == NULL) to if(node == nullptr). I've also tried just if(!node), but the null-checking line keeps being ignored and passed over.

My code is a little too long to include much more, but would you happen to know any common causes to this type of error? I haven't used null very much in C++, but it seems like it would be a relatively common error. That said, I haven't been able to find an answer to this question on SO.

Comment: Are you sure the variable is null?

Comment: Part of being courteous while asking others for help is taking your long code and reducing it to a [mcve]. If the check is being skipped, then this might as well be a function taking an `int*` and returning 1 if it's null and 0 if it's not null, then showing us that it returns 0 when given null, or directly printing something different in either case, as long as we can run it and see.

Comment: The code you've shown is correct. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Fire up the ol' debugger, drop a breakpoint on that `if` and look at `node`. If that's not an option, `std::cout << node;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't really enough information in your question to diagnose this problem, but I'll take a stab at it.  My best guess is that you aren't initializing `left` and `right` pointers when you create new nodes.  The contents of an uninitialized pointer are undefined (and won't be `NULL` unless you're extremely lucky).